# почему не работает keyup при вводе в input? js, html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

почему не работает `keyup`, не выводит `log`  при вводе в `input`?

**ошибка console**

```
jquery-3.2.1.js:5062 [Violation] Added synchronous DOM mutation listener to a 'DOMNodeInserted' event. Consider using MutationObserver to make the page more responsive.
add @ jquery-3.2.1.js:5062
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.2.1.js:4962
each @ jquery-3.2.1.js:362
each @ jquery-3.2.1.js:157
on @ jquery-3.2.1.js:4961
on @ jquery-3.2.1.js:5570
bind @ jquery-3.2.1.js:10168
bindEvents @ hoverzoom.js:1236
init @ hoverzoom.js:1666
applyOptions @ hoverzoom.js:1162
(anonymous) @ hoverzoom.js:1198
```

html

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ajax_phone').keyup(function () {
                console.log('TEXT')
            });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input list="ajax_phone" name="clients-phone" value="+7" required="" id="id_clients-phone" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Вы цепляете функцию к id, которого нет. Ваш id `id_clients-phone`, а не `ajax_phone`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id_clients-phone').keyup(function() {
    console.log('TEXT')
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input list="ajax_phone" name="clients-phone" value="+7" required="" id="id_clients-phone" autocomplete="off">
```